# "Error generating Win32 resource" in Visual Studio, Windows 7 x64

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, windows-7-x64

My co-developers and I recently upgraded machines to Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit.  Some of us are seeing a new error we used to never see when building solutions in Visual Studio (happens in both 2008 and 2010):

> Error generating Win32 resource: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

It always points to some temp file in our output folder, for example:

> MyProject\obj\Debug\CSC5123.tmp

This happens about once every four or so builds.  We then will try to run the same exact build again, and it will usually succeed.  In some cases though, it will fail again on the same project, and in same cases, it will fail on a different project.  There's really no rhyme or reason to it.  But it's very frustrating, especially when it doesn't happen until the build has been running for 20 or so seconds.

This also doesn't happen to all of our coworkers.  It happens to about one out of four developers.  For the one, it happens about one of four builds, and for the other three, it *never* happens.

Oh, and did I mention we're all using machines built from the same image? :)

Thanks in advance for any direction you can provide.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question?  I am still having the same issue.

Comment: @Reaction21 - I did not get a solution, but at some point, the error stopped occurring.  I know that's definitely not what you want to hear, and sorry I couldn't give you better news.  But I can't think of anything that happened that made this go away.  If I do, I will certainly follow up.

Comment: Happens to me - brand new machine - always files called CSC<xxx>.tmp.  It happens on various projects in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. At least it Works. Add

```
<IntermediateOutputPath>C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\vs9267.tmp\Debug\</IntermediateOutputPath>
```

to your

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
```

node in Project settings file. Volaa!

Sample code is here for my Project:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>C:\Users\ZGRSNM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\vs9267.tmp\Debug\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>C:\Users\ZGRSNM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\vs9267.tmp\Release\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```